# Sub-folders for a controller in MVC without Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create sub-folder in my default view folder in ASP.NET MVC application. I'm using MVC 4.0

Views/Device/Auto/Index.aspx

Views/Device/Auto/Edit.aspx

Views/Device/SemiAuto/Index.aspx

Views/Device/SemiAuto/Edit.aspx

Views/Device/Manual/Index.aspx

Views/Device/Manual/Edit.aspx

I have DeviceContoller and my Url should be

http://.../Device/Auto/Index and

http://.../Device/Auto/Edit

and so on for semi-auto and manual devices. I do not wish to use Area for this. I don't know how should I specify my action methods and route for it.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Any explanation for it

Answer (score 0):

In MVC, the place that a URL goes to is NOT based on the organization of view files at all. This is because a browser request doesn't hit a view directly. You might be thinking of it as being like ".aspx" files where the browser simply follows the path and filename directly. But this is not the case with MVC. In MVC, you configure a set of routes that dictate URL patterns and, for each pattern, what function it maps to on a controller. From inside this function you specify what view file will be used. It is also in here that you construct and pass the backing model. It is from these moving parts that MVC (Model-View-Controller) gets its name.

It sounds like you would do well to find a good introduction to MVC and start with the basics. That way, you'll understand how the systems interact and can plan accordingly for how to structure your application. Everything you're wanting to do can be done, but you have to understand what the moving parts are and how they interact with one another.

Answer (score 0):

The default View Engine doesn't support subfolders in the default search locations.  You could create your own view engine to add rules on how MVC should determine how to return the correct View based on the controller/action or some custom attribute.  If you go this route, you can search for [RazorViewEngine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.razorviewengine%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

But the easiest is to just tell MVC where to find the View.  Suppose you move your "About.cshtml" into a subdirectory called "Subdirectory". You can render it like so:

```
public ActionResult About()
{
    return View("~/Views/Home/SubDirectory/About.cshtml");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've already used the second approach to return view but I don't wish to implement it that way. I just want to use a standard approach for MVC like 'return View();' passing my model in it to make it easier to maintain. If you can suggest me how to register new route for it and action methods in my DeviceController then It would be perfect for me. Thanks again.

Comment: How do you determine which View to render for "Auto", "SemiAuto", and "Manual" in your Controller/Action?  Based on that answer, I could probably point you in the direction of how to create a custom RazorViewEngine to support your layout.  It's not possible to use the default RazorViewEngine with subdirectories as MVC needs a way to understand your relationship with those subdirectories and when/how/why to use them.

Comment: I wouldn't mind creating custom RazorViewEngine if its quick and easy. I wish to avoid complex scenarios to achieve it. I'm wondering If its possible to specify view name as action method parameter. For Example: Auto(string viewName ="Index");  and then I can call it by passing viewname in my Url like "http://.../Device/Auto/Index" or "http://.../Device/Auto/Edit". Inside a method I can initialize my model by checking view name and return view accordingly.

Comment: Passing the viewName into the method is going make you build your view path manually, so if you're going to that much trouble why not just specify the path as shown above?  Remember that a controller/action isn't tied to a certain file like in web forms (like the aspx files you mention).  It uses a "ViewEngine" to search for the first file that matches the criteria in the view engine based on rules...the default one uses controller and action.  Short answer, it's probably possible but not advisable if you don't know the your rules which should determine how your views get rendered.